# Checkbox change event receiving undefined value

Tags: html, angular

I have a checkbox implemented in Angular 7 application. I need to capture true or false value in the change event when the checkbox is selected or deselected.
At the moment , I am getting undefined value.

html

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" checked="checked" (change)="isInvestedSelected(s)" />
    <label for="chkInvested">Invested</label>

</div>
```

Component

```
isInvestedSelected(s) {
    console.log(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should pass $event inside the template

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" checked="checked" (change)="isInvestedSelected($event)" />
    <label for="chkInvested">Invested</label>
</div>
```

and to get value in your method:

```
isInvestedSelected(event) {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
}
```

Comment: How do  I Capture the true or false value in the change event ? Which property holds that value

Answer (score 0):

I would change
`(change)="isInvestedSelected(s)"`
to:
`(click)="isInvestedSelected($event)"`

The click event can be captured by your function and you can implement a toggle or simply change a boolean variable.

Comment: s is still undefined when using the click event

Comment: What is s?  You haven't shown that code and we can only guess why s is undefined.

Comment: The 's' is undefined cause You didn't pass Angular $event object inside your method, in the example above you passed class property 's', that's undefined

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
`(change)="isInvestedSelected(s)`
you should use 
`(change)="isInvestedSelected($event)`.

Comment: So what property will tell the checkbox is true or false

Comment: If its checked , I need to pass value true else false

Comment: Look at the property ```s.target.checked```

Answer (score 0):

Use s.source.value i.e. Use source in place of target